# How to get multiple DOM elements with chrome-remote-interface node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chrome-remote-debugging

I am just trying to build a crawler with chrome-remote-interface but i don't know how to get multiple dom elements like specific targets id,classes.

for Ex:

```
price = document.getelementbyid('price')

name= document.getelementbyid('name')
```

Code

```
    const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
    CDP((client) => {
      // Extract used DevTools domains.
      const {Page, Runtime} = client;

      // Enable events on domains we are interested in.
      Promise.all([
        Page.enable()
      ]).then(() => {
        return Page.navigate({url: 'http://example.com'})
      });

      // Evaluate outerHTML after page has loaded.
      Page.loadEventFired(() => {
        Runtime.evaluate({expression: 'document.body.outerHTML'}).then((result) => {
//How to get Multiple Dom elements
          console.log(result.result.value);
          client.close();
        });
      });
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.error('Cannot connect to browser:', err);
    });
```

Update

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

CDP((client) => {
  // Extract used DevTools domains.
  const {DOM,Page, Runtime} = client;

  // Enable events on domains we are interested in.
  Promise.all([
    Page.enable()
  ]).then(() => {
    return Page.navigate({url: 'https://someDomain.com'});
  })
  Page.loadEventFired(() => {
    const expression = `({
            test: document.getElementsByClassName('rows')),
        })`
    Runtime.evaluate({expression,returnByValue: true}).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.result) // Error
      client.close()
    })
  })
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Cannot connect to browser:', err);
});
```

Error

```
{ type: 'object',
  subtype: 'error',
  className: 'SyntaxError',
  description: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token )',
  objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":14,"id":1}' }
```

Actually I want to iterate over the list of elements But I don't know where it goes wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot move DOM object from the browser context to the Node.js context, all you can do is pass a property or whatever can be considered a JSON object. Here I'm assuming you're interested in the computed HTML.

A possible solution is:

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

CDP((client) => {
    // Extract used DevTools domains.
    const {Page, Runtime} = client;

    // Enable events on domains we are interested in.
    Promise.all([
        Page.enable()
    ]).then(() => {
        return Page.navigate({url: 'http://example.com'});
    });

    // Evaluate outerHTML after page has loaded.
    Page.loadEventFired(() => {
        const expression = `({
            name: document.getElementById('name').outerHTML,
            price: document.getElementById('price').outerHTML
        })`;
        Runtime.evaluate({
            expression,
            returnByValue: true
        }).then(({result}) => {
            const {name, price} = result.value;
            console.log(`name: ${name}`);
            console.log(`price: ${price}`);
            client.close();
        });
    });
}).on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Cannot connect to browser:', err);
});
```

The key point is returning a JSON object using `returnByValue: true`.

---

**Update:** You have an error in your expression, a trailing `)` in `...('rows')),`. But even if you fix it you'd still end up in a wrong situation because you're attempting to pass an array of DOM objects (see the first paragraph of this answer). Again, if you want just the outer HTML you can do something like:

```
// Evaluate outerHTML after page has loaded.
Page.loadEventFired(() => {
    const expression = `
        // fetch an array-like of DOM elements
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
        // create and return an array containing
        // just a property (in this case `outerHTML`)
        Array.prototype.map.call(elements, x => x.outerHTML);
    `;
    Runtime.evaluate({
        expression,
        returnByValue: true
    }).then(({result}) => {
        // this is the returned array
        const elements = result.value;
        elements.forEach((html) => {
             console.log(`- ${html}`);
        });
        client.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer But still it gives me some wired errors ill update the question